# What data to record and use in a WordPress A/B Testing Plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ab-testing

I am building A/B Testing functionality into my WordPress plugin.

I have a `Custom Post Type` named `Landing Pages`.

I have `custom meta fields/boxes` built as a `repeatable field`.  This `repeatable field` consist of multiple `Meta Fields` which have a Plus button to add a new set of these fields to the page.  Also each new set I am calling it an  **A/B Test Variation**.

The `repeatable fields` currently so far consist of these fields:

- page title  `<h1>Heading 1 value</h1>`
- page body text/HTML
- creation date for this variation set
- variation modified date
- variation active date
- variation completed date
- variation view/load counter
- variation CTA success counter/percent (form submitted or other CTA  defined somewhere)
- variation status (active/inactive)

---

Some other notes on the A/B tests

- when ab test active, save users variation into cookie, session, local storage and always serve that user that copy of page variation when they return on future visits.
- show days active on landing page create/edit screen (time past since active date and now or completed date)

---

I have never done A/B testing in any project so my question is based on what I have described here.  What other data should I be collecting and using in each A/B test variation?

Answer (score 1):

Noone other than you will know the target metric of interest (a.k.a KPIs). These typically are dollar amounts, conversion rates, subscription rates, application submission rates, etc. These frequently cannot be collected at run time and have to be converted to at analysis time.